# Does "Oracle Express 11gR2" installation can mess a Win7 system that run an oracle Application?

Tags: oracle, windows-7

As in title, I want to install "Oracle Express 11gR2" on a Win7 machine that run Opera PMS Sotware (pms for Hotel Management) via Internet explorer.

I want to write a Python script that will use cx_oracle module.
I tryed first with "instant client" : I put its PATH in windows environnement and follows tutoriel, but i still have an import error with cx_oracle module... or an error that tell me there is no oracle application on the computer...

It seems i have to install the Oracle express instead of using the "instant client".
But first, i must be sure there will be no dependancies mixing up and  messing the system...
Can i do that blindly ? I can give further info if needed

Thanks

Comment: Better to ask this on [Database Administrators Site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess Win7 machine is only an Opera PMS client. Opera PMS client machines don't depend on TNS to connect to Opera PMS Oracle Database. As you mentioned it connects over http/s.

Having an Oracle DB in the machine wouldn't harm anything on there. In fact I am doing the same on my environment.